# how can I remove the divider below actionbar sherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, divider

I'm stuck at a very ridiculous thing. 
I want to remove the divider below the action bar shown in the picture.
how can I do it?

P.S: I want to use my app for API level 8 too

[image]

Comment: You can just change the `Theme`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great tool you can use for generating an ActionBarSherlock compatible Theme.  Go to the following link and initialize it with the following settings:

- Style compatibility: **Sherlock**
- Base theme: **Dark**
- ActionBar style: **Solid**

This will remove the line below the ActionBar and allow you to choose a solid color for the ActionBar itself.  If you simply wanted to change the color of that line, you can set the ActionBar style to Transparent and change the Accent color (this is the color chosen for that line)

http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: I didn't see that tool might come in handy... I gotta tell you, this styling thing is ... . Thank you...